# Monitoring network device using PySNMP

Tags: pysnmp

Please help to provide the sample code to monitor device with:
IP: 192.168.123.123, 
MIB file name: qwert.mib, 
OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.30932.1.10.1.2.10

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't already, please kindly check http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp the pysnmp documentation. It's got examples and guides that could be helpful

Comment: Will do.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example taken from the official website:

Where you would have to change demo.snmplabs.com to 192.168.123.123 verify that your device has SNMP V2 enabled and that the password for reading community is set to 'public', if not you will have to change it accordingly.

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData('public'),
           UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0')),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0')))
)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/snmp-versions.html